# Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 ASMX Web Client 4.7 Framework Error

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I recently came a crossed this issue. I consumed an ASMX web service from a 3rd party vendor for some integration needs. On Windows 10, the service connects and runs great using 4.6-4.7 Framework. On Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2, if the service runs with the 4.7 Framework it displays the following error message,

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a send. Inner Exception: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remove
>   host.

[image]

With the 4.7 or 4.7.1 Framework installed. If it is compiled using the 4.6 Framework the web client connects without any issues.

I researched the web to great extent and have not found any mention of this problem.

Has anyone ran into this problem, knows may be happening, possible other fix besides using the 4.6 framework?